# How to use Intent in Application() class

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin

I have this code for detecting when an application closes or opens, so I can input password activity every time a user opens the application. How to use intent in Application() class?

```
class LiliApp : Application(), LifecycleObserver {
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(this)
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
fun onAppBackgrounded() {

}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
fun onAppForegrounded() {
    // var intent = Intent(this, ManagePasswordActivity::class.java)
    // startActivity(intent)
}
}
```

Comment: than do you have other solution for my case?

Comment: ah sorry - you dont want to "start application"? all you want is to start another `Activity` fron your `Application`? right?

Comment: yes, i want to start activity every aplication is foreground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to your intent

```
val i = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(i)
```